# Is sending an Ajax request on every click expensive on the client, performance wise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, onclick

<s>Is `$("*").click(function(){...})` considered expensive?</s> - [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905883/is-binding-events-in-jquery-very-expensive-or-very-inexpensive).

How about sending an ajax request on every click?

Will it cause a noticeable (perf?) problem for normal users? The app is not a game where you need to rapidly click stuff ... just a normal web app. Clicks are, I would imagine, relatively rare.

Take Stack Overflow as an example site - if this was done on SO, would it be expensive?

Note - from the linked question, I get the notiion that `$("*").click()` would have horrible perf on its own, at least on some browsers. Is there a better technique to still do what I want (send an ajax request on every click), without being a perf hog? Is [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) the answer?

**Note** - I'm focusing on the client, because I am not expecting a tremendous number of concurrent users. I believe the server can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch clicks everywhere, you should use the `delegate` method instead of binding all elements:

```
$('body').delegate('*', 'click', function(){ ... });
```

This will bind a single event handler on the body element and handle events when they bubble up from the elements that are clicked on.

Sending an AJAX request on every click would not affect the browser much, but it might be heavy on the server if you have a lot of users. Also, if someone clicks several times in a row, the requests would queue up on the server, and it would take a while for all the responses to get back to the browser.

Comment: How does this compare to @Gidon's solution?

Comment: It's worth noting that from jQuery 1.7 onwards, `.delegete()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: 1. This does not seem to catch all clicks. 2. Sometimes a single click generates a ton (~ 10) events. 3. When I changed `.delegate()` to` like jQuery suggested, it stopped working altogether. I don't have a sscce handy.

Comment: 1. It won't catch clicks that are handled by elements themselves. To catch those you would *have* to bind the event on every single element. 2. Odd. Have you tried `preventDefault` ? 3. The order of the parameters is different between `delegate` and `on`.

Comment: Gideons solution catches the event on the body element only, just like using `$(document.body).click(...);`. The handler is not called in the scope of the clicked element, that's why it needs to use `e.target`.

Answer (score 1):

Client wise, if you don't send too many ajax request at the same time, it should be ok. 
I found that when I have around 30 open ajax request running it will slow stuff down a lot (even in Chrome, which would freeze).

You problem might be more at the server side, which has to handle all those requests.

**Update**

```
$(document.body).on('click' , function(e) {
   //here i handle all clicks in the document
   //the source of the click is
   var src = e.target;
});
```

Comment: I'm not expecting a lot of concurrent users, and each active user will only click every 1-30 seconds. The server should be ok.

Comment: So ... would you use `$("*").click(...)`, or something else?

Comment: $(document.body').on('click', function(e) { /* bla */ });

Comment: this way you have only one eventhandler (not hundreds), if you care to know what was clicked, you can check the target property of the eventObject  (e in my example)

Comment: This behaves slightly different than `.delegate`, but still similar caveats: 1. Not all clicks are captured. 2. Clicks generate two events  instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

nah! ajax requests happnes behind the scenes. Your users will not notice. All the analytics tools use this so I wonder why we should be worried about that.

Stackoverflow I am pretty sure will have they own click trackers running behind the scenes.

I you have good hardware and good bandwidth throughput it should be Ok with all means

Comment: Do you know it's not a problem, or is this a theory? Do you have a citation?

Comment: its not a problem thats for sure. we stress tested our site with many randomly generated click through testcomplete. Sites like clicktale if you ever use it pretty much do the same thing. You can also look for optimizing your click tracking. say for example you can keep recording clicks for a session and post that data to the server just before user leaves the page or may in batch of 100. Generally ajax requests are pretty much similar to normal website traffic. say google home page? how about serving that billions of time. or google auto suggestion box

Comment: Did you test the experience for the end user (with different browsers), or just the server load?

Comment: well we tested the server load as well as user experience so with us it was ok. We tested on our LAN. we used chrome and FF btw. On the other hand server can take that much load. So if we say its a DDOS or DOS (denial of service) sort of requests then you are stuffed anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending server requests on every click event, then that can create a burden on the server. Consider if you have 100 people using it simultaneously, and they click every 3 seconds - in 10 seconds thats over 900 requests that the web server has to field responses to.

Be careful doing this. If you do go this route, be sure to take advantage of browser caching for responses.

Comment: Only do this if you have lots of bandwidth, and preferably a content delivery network

Comment: Updated question - Focusing on the client right now, I don't believe this will create a server load for our usage pattern.

Comment: In that case, if you have a lot of timing out requests (the users bandwidth must be taken into account also) then it will create a poor user experience for your end users. Be sure that your requests are structured correctly and that concurrent requests arent dependent on the outcome of others etc.